# whats the easiest way to find out if at least thee of 6 floats with the random value of 1-6 have the same value (in c#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

im trying to program an easy dice game for mobile in unity with c# (its called 10000, maybe you know it).

In the game you have 6 dices, you get when you roll for exapmle three times a 6 600 points for four times a 3 3000 points and so on.

Thats why i have to check if there are at least 3 dices with the same number, and with `Mathf.Approximately`
and a lot of if's the code would be really ugly and long.

So whats the easiest way to get around this problem?

Comment: use `int` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// cubes values
int[] values = new int[6]
{
    3, 4, 3, 6, 1, 3
};

// group values (key => value, value => count key)
var group = values.GroupBy(v => v);

// if there are 3 or more identical cubes
if (group.Any(g => g.Count() >= 3))
{

}
```